# Oracle Apex IG force user to have filter on column

Tags: oracle-apex

I need to force user to have filter on column with date. Dataset is rly big and it must-have. I know how to force user to have any filter. Just add to "Where":

```
:apex$f1 is not null
```

But I need to find how to force user to have filter on specific column

Comment: I don't think you can easily force this in an IG. However you could have a separate page item that sets a value which you then use as filter in your IG query. Only run the report if that page item is not NULL.

Comment: I did with subquery in Where clause. If there is no filter on that column on user session there is no data. With correct hints on views, that works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like i wrote in comment this is solution (I couldn't find better one)
In 'Where Clause' I added this

```
EXISTS (SELECT /*+ NO_UNNEST */ F.*, R.*, C.* FROM apex_appl_page_ig_rpt_filters F, APEX_APPL_PAGE_IG_RPTS R, APEX_APPL_PAGE_IG_COLUMNS C
WHERE 1=1 
AND F.report_id = R.report_id AND C.column_id = F.column_id
AND F.APPLICATION_ID = 100 AND F.PAGE_ID = 100
AND C.NAME = 'MY_COLUMN_NAME'
AND C.REGION_NAME = 'MY_REGION_NAME'
AND R.SESSION_ID = :APP_SESSION)
```

This checks setting of IG in apex objects. In addition you just need to wrote in Messages "When No Data Found" something about that column that is required, just to inform users.